# Group by two columns at once or?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a report using the following query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Date',
    CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2)) AS 'Username',
    COUNT(admin_id) AS 'Surveys Carried Out'
FROM
    `customer_surveys`
LEFT JOIN `admin` ON customer_surveys.admin_id = admin.adminid
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

It needs to group by the date (as it's a day by day report) and the admin_id (as it's a count of how many surveys have been carried out by that ID)

This in theory, should work. But look at what it returns, and comparing it to the actual data, it's displaying it day by day but merging the admin_ids so the first occuring one on that day is the one that displays. Any help?

Comment: You haven't grouped by `admin_id`.

Comment: Doh! I apoligise. The article I read online said I couldn't group by two at once. Maybe I should've checked first.

Comment: So can we delete this question?

Comment: May help someone searching but in terms of my needs it's all completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to display records of dates for every admin, you should have to group it by date and by admin_id *atleast*

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), admin_id
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to add a `GROUP BY admin_id`:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Date',
    CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2)) AS 'Username',
    COUNT(admin_id) AS 'Surveys Carried Out'
FROM `customer_surveys`
LEFT JOIN `admin` 
   ON customer_surveys.admin_id = admin.adminid
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), admin_id
```

Grouping by both will get you the values by `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')` and `admin_id`

Answer (score 1):

Don't you need the non-aggregates all in the group by?  Concat isn't an aggregrate

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') AS 'Date',
    CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2)) AS 'Username',
    COUNT(admin_id) AS 'Surveys Carried Out'
FROM
    `customer_surveys`
LEFT JOIN `admin` ON customer_surveys.admin_id = admin.adminid
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), CONCAT(UCASE(MID(name,1,1)),MID(name,2))
```